# How to move on to next client in C# tcp server correctly?

Tags: c#, tcp

```
            tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6007);
            tcpListener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                while(true)
                    parseRequest(sr.ReadLine());
            }
```

This is essentially the code I am using for a C# tcp server. The server needs to handle multiple connections, but not simultaneously, so it can work with one client, and when that client disconnects continue on to the next client. The client can send a variable amount of messages, and the server needs to process these messages.

The problem is when the first client disconnects it never connects to the next client. I tried adding code in my second while loop to check "if (!Client.Connected) break; " but Connected always returned true, even after my client application had closed out. What can I do to be able to connect to the second client after the first has disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a new thread or register a new listener for each accepted socket, instead of processing it entirely in the same loop that is accepting new clients. The accept loop should do nothing else.